# oracle/sql/CharacterSet has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, odbc

I am running a web application on WebLogic server.
i am giving ODBC driver in junit.xml file because i am running the junit test cases.
While running the code, below error is coming.

```
oracle/sql/CharacterSet has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.nec.jp.watool.util.text.OracleJdbcMS932Corrector.process(OracleJdbcMS932Corrector.java:87)
at com.nec.jp.watool.util.text.StringConverter.convert(StringConverter.java:138)
```

I have configured the different version of ODBC drives starting from 6 to 8.
I am running my code on java 8.
I do not find any solution on that. Kindly help on this.

Comment: Classfile version 54 means it was compiled with Java 10, it won't run under Java 8.

Comment: The error suggests you are using ojdbc10 (which is for Java 10), instead of ojdbc8 (which is for Java 8).